# Display number of events per day in SharePoint 2007 Calendar

Tags: calculated-column, sharepoint-calendar

I have a SharePoint list which contains project name, start date, and due date. I have created a SharePoint calendar based on this list that displays the contents of this list in a calendar format. What I need my calendar to do is display the **number of events** for a given day, instead of displaying the list items that occur on that day.

For example on September 4, instead of having "wash the dishes", "clean the room", and "mop the floor" on the calendar, I simply want the number "3". Ideally, when I click the number, it would take me to the daily view that will show me the project titles for that day.

I have tried accomplishing this by creating a calculated field that displays the number of events per day, but COUNTIF is not available in SharePoint. Is there any way of doing this with out of the box SharePoint 2007? My client does not have SharePoint Designer and has a very limited collection of available webparts.